# Creating appspotmail address to receive eMail in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, email

I set up an application in GAE and I want to be able to receive eMails.

The documentation says that:

> You can set up your app to receive incoming email at
>   string@appid.appspotmail.com addresses
>   [GAE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Receiving_mail_in_Java)

I did not found any possibility to create a mail in this form (e.g. *service@appid.appspotmail.com*) in the application.

Can somebody help me how to set up an appspot mail address and to assign it to the application? (I do not know if I need to assign the address inside the permissions settings of the app or if it is sufficient to only put in the *web.xml* of the application)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is adding the following in your `appengine-web.xml` :

```
<inbound-services>
  <service>mail</service>
</inbound-services>
```

Source: [GAE documentation - Receiving Mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Receiving_mail)

Once you have done that, any address in `@yourappname.appspotmail.com` will be valid.